# How to minmize an interpolated function?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, minimization

I have interpolated a discretized function over a 2D surface analogous to the example in the code below from [scipy.interpolate.griddata](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html)  and now I want to minimize this function using scipy.optimize? any idea or solution?

Thanks for your help.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def func(x, y):
    return x*(1-x)*np.cos(4*np.pi*x) * np.sin(4*np.pi*y**2)**2
grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[0:1:100j, 0:1:200j]
points = np.random.rand(1000, 2)
values = func(points[:,0], points[:,1])
grid_z0 = griddata(points, values, (grid_x, grid_y), method='cubic')
plt.subplot(221)
plt.imshow(func(grid_x, grid_y).T, extent=(0,1,0,1), origin='lower')
plt.plot(points[:,0], points[:,1], 'k.', ms=1)
plt.title('Original')
plt.subplot(222)
plt.imshow(grid_z0.T, extent=(0,1,0,1), origin='lower')
plt.title('cubic')
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(6, 6)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

`griddata` returns an array, so you can literally find the indices of the smallest number in that array using `numpy.argmin` - no need for any sophisticated optimization with `scipy.optimize` because there's no function to optimise - you only have that array of numbers.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @ForceBru for your answer, is very helpful, however, is there any way to minimize an interpolated function knowing her values and its gradient at some nodes in a Mesh? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Lemin, you could try [`interp2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp2d) - it returns a callable and lets you calculate derivatives

Comment: Thanks a lot ! will try it